# How to create an AMI of an instance using aws cli command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ami

How can i create an AMI of the instance using the cli command ? . I ahve referred the official documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-image.html . I also have need to create a snapshot of the attached volume

This is the command i am trying ,

`aws ec2 create-image --instance-id "instance-id"   --name  "my-image-nov-9"`

But I need additional parameters to include the tag for the created image

Comment: Please expand your question. What exactly is the desired end result? What errors do you get? What are your current obstacles? What have you tried?

Comment: use `--tag-specifications`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CLI command to create the AMI of an instance

```
aws ec2 create-image --instance-id instance-id --name my-image-nov-9 --no-reboot --tag-specifications "ResourceType=image,Tags=[{Key=project,Value=test-project,Key=team,Value=development}]"
```

> --no-reboot | --reboot (boolean)
>
> Indicates whether or not the instance should be automatically rebooted
> before creating the image. Specify one of the following values:
>
> Default: false
>
> true - The instance is not rebooted before creating the image.

> --tag-specifications (list)
>
> The tags to apply to the AMI and snapshots on creation. You can tag
> the AMI, the snapshots, or both.
>
> To tag the AMI, the value for ResourceType must be image . To tag the
> snapshots that are created of the root volume and of other Amazon EBS
> volumes that are attached to the instance, the value for ResourceType
> must be snapshot . The same tag is applied to all of the snapshots
> that are created.

Comment: This worked , Thankyou for the detailed answer .